# XSLT variable not working

Tags: xslt

I have the following piece of XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:variable name="condition">(coasts='Adriatic Sea')or(coasts='Mediterranean Sea')</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="cia">
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <table border="1">
       <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Inflation rate</th>
       </tr> 
       <xsl:for-each select="country">
        <xsl:if test="{$condition}">
        <tr>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@capital"/>
         </td> 
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@total_area"/>
         </td> 
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@population"/>
         </td> 
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="@inflation"/>
         </td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If put the conditional expression directly in the if element the code works fine, however, my problem is that when I assign the same conditional expression to the variable and then reference it in the if element it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: @user734702: If you are after some kind of dynamic evaluation, you will need to find or implement some extension fucntion for your XSLT processor. Unless you provide details about this expression construction that can lead to another kind of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- The brackets in `<xsl:if test="{$condition}">` are unnecessary; use `<xsl:if test="$condition">`
- Use the following `xsl:variable` construct:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="condition" 
          select="(coasts='Adriatic Sea')or(coasts='Mediterranean Sea')"/>
  ```
- When you had the condition in your `xsl:if` the test was performed relative to each `country`. This is not the case in a top-level variable. The value of the variable is the *result* of the expression, not the expression *itself*. If you insist on a variable, then initialize it inside the loop.

See the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:template match="cia">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Capital</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Population</th>
                        <th>Inflation rate</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="country">
                        <xsl:variable name="condition"
                            select="(coasts='Adriatic Sea') or 
                                    (coasts='Mediterranean Sea')" />
                        <xsl:if test="$condition">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@capital" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@total_area" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@population" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@inflation" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<cia>
    <country name="test1" inflation="22">
        <coasts>Adriatic Sea</coasts>
    </country>
    <country name="test2" inflation="7">
        <coasts>No match</coasts>
    </country>
</cia>
```

Output (only the first `country` passes the test):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Inflation rate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that you don't really even need a separate condition; it's better to select just the desired elements in the first place. This loop produces the same output:

```
<xsl:for-each
    select="country[(coasts='Adriatic Sea') or
                     coasts='Mediterranean Sea')]">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@capital" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@total_area" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@population" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@inflation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="country">
```

**with**

```
               <xsl:apply templates select="country"/>
```

**also, add these templates**:

```
 <xsl:template match="country"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "country[coasts='Adriatic Sea' 
         or                                        
           coasts='Mediterranean Sea'
         ]">
<xsl:template match=
  "country[coasts='Adriatic Sea'
         or
           coasts='Mediterranean Sea'
         ]">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@capital"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@total_area"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@population"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@inflation"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Did you note that the `<xsl:if>` "magically" disappeared?

**Of course, this code can be improved even further**, but you haven't provided neither an instance of the XML document on which the transformation is to be applied, nor the desired output.